# In Bigquery: How to fetch column value matching with other table but retaining the same column value if not matched

Tags: join, google-bigquery, left-join, case

**Scenario:**
Have got two bigquery tables with same columns. Have to compare these two tables w.r.t. Category and Article,
i)  if same present in table_2, have to fetch 'Flow' column from table_2
ii) otherwise, retain the same Flow column from Table_1 itself.

**Table_1:**

```
Category    Article     Flow
AA          11          Apple
AA          12          Orange
BB          13          Lemon
CC          14
```

**Table_2:**

```
Category    Article     Flow
AA          11          Melon
BB          13          Pine
```

**Resultant Table:**

```
Category    Article     Flow
AA          11          Melon
AA          12          Orange
BB          13          Pine
CC          14
```

**Tried_Out Query:**

```
select t1.Category, t1.Article, t2.Flow
from t1 left join t2
on t1.Category=t2.Category and t1.Article=t2.Article
```

Help me resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try [left join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join):

```
with table_1 as (
  select 'AA' as category, 11 as article, 'Apple' as flow UNION ALL
  select 'AA', 12, 'Orange' UNION ALL
  select 'BB', 13, 'Lemon' UNION ALL
  select 'CC', 14, null
),
table_2 as (
  select 'AA' as category, 11 as article, 'Melon' as flow UNION ALL
  select 'BB', 13, 'Pine'
)
select
  table_1.category,
  table_1.article,
  ifnull(table_2.flow, table_1.flow) as flow
from table_1 left join table_2 using(category, article)
```

[image]